# Código para abrir link nova aba com contador

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

não tenho experiencia nenhuma com programação, gostaria de uma ajuda: encontrei esse código na internet:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var contador = 20;
function contar() {
    document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contador;
    contador--;
}
function redirecionar() {
    contar();
    if (contador == 0) {
        document.location.href = 'https://google.com';
    }
}
setInterval(redirecionar, 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Link vai expirar em... <label id="contador"></label></p>
</body>
</html>
```

mas esse código faz a função de redirecionar para o link informado após um tempo determinado no contador.

Eu gostaria de um código que abrisse o link informado numa nova aba, mantendo a aba atual aberta, após um tempo determinado no contador.
Desde já agradeço

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Abrir uma nova nova aba ou janela sem ação do usuário vai contra as diretrizes de segurança dos navegadores e eles bloqueiam esse esquema.

Answer (score 2):

Para abrir numa nova aba (ou pop-up) utilize o `window.open`:

```
window.open("https://google.com");
```

Pode ver mais informações em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open.

---

*No seu caso inclua o `window.open` dentro da função `redirecionar`.*

Answer (score -1):

Pra deixar tudo bem simples pra você, que não tem contato com programação.
Basta mudar o valor da variável seu_link, para o link que você deseja que seja aberto em uma nova guia.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var seu_link = "https://google.com/"
var contador = 20;
function contar() {
    document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contador;
    contador--;
}
function redirecionar() {
    contar();
    if (contador == 0) {
        window.open(seu_link);
    }
}
setInterval(redirecionar, 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Link vai expirar em... <label id="contador"></label></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: caramba, top top top maninho... funcionou do jeito que eu queria. me manda teu pix para eu te enviar um agradecimento

Answer (score -2):

Um erro simples que notei neste código, é que o contador não para no momento em que chega a zero. E continua imprimindo na tela -1, -2, -3... Infinitamente.

O seu problema já foi solucionado pelos colegas, então vou citar apenas a parte do contador.

Crie uma condição para a sua função `contar()` já que ela é chamada pela função redirecionar, a cada 1 segundo. Um simples `if` checando se o `contador é maior ou igual a zero` já resolve, pois após chegar a zero será redirecionado, mas a função ainda iria chamar o `contar()`, porém como o contador seria menor que `zero`, então ele não cai mais dentro do seu `if` e não imprime mais na tela.

Segue função modificada:

```
function contar() {
    if (contador >= 0) {
        document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contador; 
        contador--;
    }
}
```

Código completo:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var seu_link = "https://google.com/"
    var contador = 20;
    function contar() {
        if (contador >= 0) {
            document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contador; 
            contador--;
        }
    }
    function redirecionar() {
        contar();
        if (contador == 0) {
            window.open(seu_link);
     }
    }
    setInterval(redirecionar, 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Link vai expirar em... <label id="contador"></label></p>
</body>
</html>
```